# storing large numbers of images in ms access

Tags: ms-access, ole

I have a inventory/Contact database where I need to store a lot of images (10k items, 1k people). Now, obviously ole object is out of the question due to the sheer bloat.

Is there a better way to do this, such as storing the pathway to the image ( would be stored in a folder with the database) and having that image displayed where I need it(this would be great because some items are repeated)? Is there anyway to do this? (also, i really need to have a filebrowser to the actual image instead of typing the path manually (that would be hell))

Comment: storing the path is probably the best way to go and you can use the `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` object to get the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a concept

```
Sub Locate_File()
   Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
   Dim file_path As String
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fDialog  
    'Set the title of the dialog box.
    .Title = "Please select one or more files"

    'Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

    'Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
    'user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
    'False, the user clicked Cancel.
    If .Show = True Then
       file_path = .SelectedItems(1)
       Copy_file(file_path,Right(file_path, Len(file_path) - InStrRev(file_path, "\")))
    Else
       MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
    End If
  End With
End

Sub Copy_file(old_path As String, file_name As String)
  Dim fs As Object
  Dim images_path As String
  images_path = CurrentProject.Path & "\images\"
  Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  fs.CopyFile old_path, images_path  & file_name
  Set fs = Nothing
  'Update your database with the file location of images_path & file_name
End
```

You may need to make changes and you must require the Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library for FileDialog to work. Much of the FileDialog code was taken from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243865%28v=office.12%29.aspx)