# Upload video file (mp4,mpeg) in access database using vb

Tags: ms-access, vba

is it possible to upload video file using access database and vb? i am beginner in programming and our project is all about uploading files. Can anyone help me? I used access database because that is the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Would the video files be uploaded to a local network server or to a website?

If you are uploading the files to to a local server, you could have access:

1 Open up a file dialog to browse to the file to be uploaded.

2 Copy that file to a specific directory on your network, making sure the filename is unique or possibly creating a file name based on the original file name and date of upload. ie filename_datetime.

See the following answer for steps 1 and 2: [storing large numbers of images in ms access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796008/storing-large-numbers-of-images-in-ms-access/19796538?noredirect=1#comment30004181_19796538)

3 Maintain information in a table with fields for: filename, file location, user, upload date, friendly file name and possibly links to other tables such as clientID etc.

If you are uploading the files to a web server, you could do this in access, but you'd probably be better off managing the uploading and listing of files in a website.  You could build it yourself or look into what you already have, as many content management systems will have this kind of file management built in.

Comment: to local network. uhmn. can you give me example of the whole code? i really don't have idea how to make it . I only know how top opendialogfile and set the file type to mp4 formats then i don't know how i can upload it to access. btw. Thank you very much for your answer.